# Отображение нескольких подсказок при нажатии на блок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать следующий функционал: пользователь нажимает на блок (в примере ниже это li) и над другими блоками появляется текст из атрибута title. При чем текст должен появится над всем указанными блоками и исчезнуть по повторному нажатию на кнопку (или на li). Пробовал сделать вот так

```js
function showTittles() {
  var buttShow = document.getElementById("buttShow");
  var titlesContainer = document.querySelectorAll("#servicelist1, #servicelist2, #servicelist3");
  var buttonsArr = document.getElementById("buttonsArr");
  var listItem = buttonsArr.querySelectorAll("#redBlc, #greenBlc, #blueBlc");
  var showingTooltip;
  var titles = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < titlesContainer.length; i++) {
    titles.push(titlesContainer[i].getAttribute('title'));
  }
  
  listItem.forEach (function (i) {
  listItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    switch (i) {
      case i === 0:
        addTitle(0);
        break;

      case i === 1:
        addTitle(1);
        break;

      case i === 2:
        addTitle(2);
        break;

      default:
        consol.log("жми!");
        break;
    }
  })
  })

}



function addTitle(elem) {
  var target = titlesContainer[elem];
  var tooltipElem = document.createElement('div');
  tooltipElem.className = 'tooltip-title';
  tooltipElem.innerHTML = titles[elem];
  document.body.appendChild(tooltipElem);

  var coords = target.getBoundingClientRect();

  var left = coords.left + (target.offsetWidth - tooltipElem.offsetWidth) / 2;
  if (left < 0) left = 0; // не вылезать за левую границу окна

  var top = coords.top - tooltipElem.offsetHeight - 5;
  if (top < 0) { // не вылезать за верхнюю границу окна
    top = coords.top + target.offsetHeight + 5;
  }
  tooltipElem.style.left = left + 'px';
  tooltipElem.style.top = top + 'px';
  showingTooltip = tooltipElem
}

showTittles();
```

```css
.servicelist {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#servicelist1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#servicelist2 {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#servicelist3 {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.tooltip-title {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: italic 14px/1.3 arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div id="servicelist1" title="Якутия" class="servicelist"></div>
<div id="servicelist2" title="Анадрь" class="servicelist"></div>
<div id="servicelist3" title="Андатра" class="servicelist"></div>

<ul class="btn-clk" id="buttonsArr">
  <li id="redBlc">Показать красный тултип</li>
  <li id="greenBlc">Показать зеленый тултип</li>
  <li id="blueBlc">Показать голубой тултип</li>
</ul>
```

Некоторый код брал из [этого](http://plnkr.co/edit/CEYfQIQmvQO45sEveChc?p=preview) примера

Сейчас он ругается на addEventListener и я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на отдельный li появлялся личный title над каждым блоком.

P.S в проекте уже есть jquery и bootstrap, так что если легче будет с ними, то подойдет решение с применением этих инструментов, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял что вам нужно. Написал как понял. Уточните/напишите если что не так.

В примере используется [jquery 2.1.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js)

```js
(function($) {
 $('li').click(function(){ 
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $(document).find('.servicelist').html('');
 
 
  $(document).find('.servicelist').html($(document).find('[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('title'));
  
 
   
 
 });
})( jQuery );
```

```css
/* Удалить CSS */
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.servicelist {
    margin: 5px;
}
ul#buttonsArr {
    width: 100%;
}
/* конец CSS */

.servicelist {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#servicelist1 {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#servicelist2 {
  border: 1px solid #0f0;
}

#servicelist3 {
  border: 1px solid #00f;
}

.tooltip-title {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #b3c9ce;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font: italic 14px/1.3 arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="servicelist1" data-id="redBlc" title="Якутия" class="servicelist"></div>
<div id="servicelist2" data-id="greenBlc" title="Анадрь" class="servicelist"></div>
<div id="servicelist3" data-id="blueBlc" title="Андатра" class="servicelist"></div>

<ul class="btn-clk" id="buttonsArr">
  <li id="redBlc">Показать красный тултип</li>
  <li id="greenBlc">Показать зеленый тултип</li>
  <li id="blueBlc">Показать голубой тултип</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это работает хорошо, но мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на один li, например, на "Показать голубой тултип" показывались тултипы сразу во всех 3 блоках) цветовую разницу добавил, только чтобы различить можно было на макете страницы)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев наримир титл красного у всех трёх блоков?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев если правильно понял, это делается легче, обновил ответ.

Comment: Здорово! Пока Вас не было я уже опробовал нечто похожее https://jsfiddle.net/vn8kw9wk/ но этот способ не работает с svg :( Если я создам отдельный вопрос с уточнением темы про svg вы сможете мне с этим помочь?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев ваш вариант работает чучуть неверно, получается два клика, один очистить другой добавить.  А что по поводу svg ? Почему не работает, и что именно ?

Comment: вот отдельный вопрос по этой теме:)

Comment: Если на этот вопрос решение верно, будьте добры отметить как правильный ответ :)